# Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, for-loop, synchronization

I am running an event loop of the following form:

```
var i;
var j = 10;
for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {

    asynchronousProcess(callbackFunction() {
        alert(i);
    });
}
```

I am trying to display a series of alerts showing the numbers 0 through 10. The problem is that by the time the callback function is triggered, the loop has already gone through a few iterations and it displays a higher value of `i`. Any recommendations on how to fix this?

Comment: How about adding the i parameter to the `asynchronousProcess` function? Which can pass it on to the callbackFunction

Comment: Pass `i` into the callbackFunction to ensure that you handle the value of that variable as it was at the time the function was called - rather than after the function returns.

Comment: check our this link to better and deep understand [Morzila Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)

Answer (score 325, accepted):

The `for` loop runs immediately to completion while all your asynchronous operations are started.  When they complete some time in the future and call their callbacks, the value of your loop index variable `i` will be at its last value for all the callbacks.

This is because the `for` loop does not wait for an asynchronous operation to complete before continuing on to the next iteration of the loop and because the async callbacks are called some time in the future.  Thus, the loop completes its iterations and THEN the callbacks get called when those async operations finish.  As such, the loop index is "done" and sitting at its final value for all the callbacks.

To work around this, you have to uniquely save the loop index separately for each callback.  In Javascript, the way to do that is to capture it in a function closure.  That can either be done be creating an inline function closure specifically for this purpose (first example shown below) or you can create an external function that you pass the index to and let it maintain the index uniquely for you (second example shown below).

As of 2016, if you have a fully up-to-spec ES6 implementation of Javascript, you can also use `let` to define the `for` loop variable and it will be uniquely defined for each iteration of the `for` loop (third implementation below).  But, note this is a late implementation feature in ES6 implementations so you have to make sure your execution environment supports that option.

**Use .forEach() to iterate since it creates its own function closure**

```
someArray.forEach(function(item, i) {
    asynchronousProcess(function(item) {
        console.log(i);
    });
});
```

**Create Your Own Function Closure Using an IIFE**

```
var j = 10;
for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    (function(cntr) {
        // here the value of i was passed into as the argument cntr
        // and will be captured in this function closure so each
        // iteration of the loop can have it's own value
        asynchronousProcess(function() {
            console.log(cntr);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

**Create or Modify External Function and Pass it the Variable**

If you can modify the `asynchronousProcess()` function, then you could just pass the value in there and have the `asynchronousProcess()` function the cntr back to the callback like this:

```
var j = 10;
for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    asynchronousProcess(i, function(cntr) {
        console.log(cntr);
    });
}
```

**Use ES6 `let`**

If you have a Javascript execution environment that fully supports ES6, you can use `let` in your `for` loop like this:

```
const j = 10;
for (let i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    asynchronousProcess(function() {
        console.log(i);
    });
}
```

`let` declared in a `for` loop declaration like this will create a unique value of `i` for each invocation of the loop (which is what you want).

**Serializing with promises and async/await**

If your async function returns a promise, and you want to serialize your async operations to run one after another instead of in parallel and you're running in a modern environment that supports `async` and `await`, then you have more options.

```
async function someFunction() {
    const j = 10;
    for (let i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        // wait for the promise to resolve before advancing the for loop
        await asynchronousProcess();
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

This will make sure that only one call to `asynchronousProcess()` is in flight at a time and the `for` loop won't even advance until each one is done.  This is different than the previous schemes that all ran your asynchronous operations in parallel so it depends entirely upon which design you want.  Note: `await` works with a promise so your function has to return a promise that is resolved/rejected when the asynchronous operation is complete.  Also, note that in order to use `await`, the containing function must be declared `async`.

**Run asynchronous operations in parallel and use `Promise.all()` to collect results in order**

```
 function someFunction() {
     let promises = [];
     for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          promises.push(asynchonousProcessThatReturnsPromise());
     }
     return Promise.all(promises);
 }

 someFunction().then(results => {
     // array of results in order here
     console.log(results);
 }).catch(err => {
     console.log(err);
 });
```

Comment: Added second option if you can modify the `asycronouseProcess()` function.

Comment: Added ES6 `let` implementation.

Comment: Would it be wrong to increment a counter and then check if it equals `j` inside the asynchronous function?

Comment: @Jake1986 - It depends upon what you're trying to do and how the code is written.  I can't really tell from your brief comment.  If you want, you can ask your own question and show the code you're asking about.

Comment: Worth to read for an explanation - async/await

Comment: Possible update for your ES6 section. Seems like you can use a for-of loop in the same way instead of a regular for Loop. Which might be an easier syntax for some users to understand.

Comment: @SeanMC - I follow what you're saying, but the question doesn't actually show an array of anything so it doesn't seem like this question is actually about iterating an array (or some iterable) with is what `for/of` is about.

Comment: thanks! the *for(value of values)* vs *for(let value of values)* is really subtle.

Comment: This is one of the clearest examples of async behavior in JS I've every read. Do you have a blog?

Comment: @DemianSims - I don't have a blog, but I write a lot of answers here.  You could go see my most popular answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00?tab=answers&sort=votes) and skim the list for topics of interest.  I do post a lot on asynchronous, promise and nodejs stuff.

Answer (score 33):

`async await` is here
(ES7), so you can do this kind of things very easily now.

```
  var i;
  var j = 10;
  for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    await asycronouseProcess();
    alert(i);
  }
```

**Remember, this works only if `asycronouseProcess` is returning a `Promise`**

If `asycronouseProcess` is not in your control then you can make it return a `Promise` by yourself like this

```
function asyncProcess() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    asycronouseProcess(()=>{
      resolve();
    })
  })
}
```

Then replace this line `await asycronouseProcess();` by `await asyncProcess();`

**Understanding `Promises` before even looking into `async await` is must**
(Also read about support for `async await`)

Comment: Will each iteration of the loop wait?

Comment: @Shamoon yes. It will wait (if asycronouseProcess() returns a promise)

Comment: @Praveena. Returning a promise from an async function solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

> Any recommendation on how to fix this?

Several. You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    asycronouseProcess(function (i) {
        alert(i);
    }.bind(null, i));
}
```

Or, if your browser supports [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) (it will be in the next ECMAScript version, however Firefox already supports it since a while) you could have:

```
for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    let k = i;
    asycronouseProcess(function() {
        alert(k);
    });
}
```

Or, you could do the job of `bind` manually (in case the browser doesn't support it, but I would say you can implement a shim in that case, it should be in the link above):

```
for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    asycronouseProcess(function(i) {
        return function () {
            alert(i)
        }
    }(i));
}
```

I usually prefer `let` when I can use it (e.g. for Firefox add-on); otherwise `bind` or a custom [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function (that doesn't need a context object).

Comment: The ECMAScript example is a very good one to demonstrate what `let` can do.

Comment: Is `asyncronouseProcess` in all the answers some kind of placeholder? I'm getting "not defined".

Comment: The `asyncronouseProcess` is part of the original question, so yeah, it's normal if it gives to you "not defined". You can just replace it with any async function if you want to check the original issue and how the proposed solution works. For example: `function asycronouseProcess(fn){ setTimeout(fn, 100);}`

Answer (score 4):

```js
var i = 0;
var length = 10;

function for1() {
  console.log(i);
  for2();
}

function for2() {
  if (i == length) {
    return false;
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    i++;
    for1();
  }, 500);
}
for1();
```

Here is a sample functional approach to what is expected here.

Answer (score 4):

ES2017: You can wrap the async code inside a function(say XHRPost) returning a promise( Async code inside the promise).

Then call the function(XHRPost) inside the for loop but with the magical Await keyword. :)

```js
let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
let url = 'http://sumersin/forum.social.json';

function XHRpost(i) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    let params = 'id=nobot&%3Aoperation=social%3AcreateForumPost&subject=Demo' + i + '&message=Here%20is%20the%20Demo&_charset_=UTF-8';
    http.open('POST', url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log("Done " + i + "<<<<>>>>>" + http.readyState);
          if(http.readyState == 4){
              console.log('SUCCESS :',i);
              resolve();
          }
         }
    http.send(params);       
    });
 }
 
(async () => {
    for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        await XHRpost(i);
       }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript code runs on a single thread, so you cannot principally block to wait for the first loop iteration to complete before beginning the next without seriously impacting page usability.

The solution depends on what you really need.  If the example is close to exactly what you need, @Simon's suggestion to pass `i` to your async process is a good one.