# Variable suddenly becomes undefined in the callback to an Angular $resource function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I'm building a function in Node that queries my `mongoDB` database and returns some results into an object. I'm having trouble getting the object set up correctly though. Here's my code:

**Function to call the MongoDB lookup**

```
  $scope.listItems = $resource('http://10.1.1.21\\:3000/api/uniques/:query');

  var itemsToList = [
    'designer',
    'store',
    'category'
  ]

  $scope.uniqueLists = {};

  for(var i = 0; i<itemsToList.length; i++){
    $scope.uniqueLists[itemsToList[i]] = [];  
    $scope.listItems.get({query:itemsToList[i]}, function(data){ 
        console.log(itemsToList); // Returns ["designer", "store", "Category"] x3
        console.log(itemsToList[i]); // Returns undefined, undefined, undefined
        console.log('i = ' + i); // Returns 3, 3, 3 (which is really odd, ideas?)

         $scope.uniqueLists[i] = data.query;

    });
  }
```

Issues with this code are in the comments above. Bizarrely, `i == 3` for all 3 loops, when it should equal `0`, `1`, then finish at `2`.

**My question is**

Can anybody shed light on what's going on here? It may have something to do with Node's asynchronous behaviour, but I'm really at a loss here.

**Additional Info**

My `ExpressJS` call that `$scope.listItems` is accessing is here, as you can see `express` makes data available through `res`(ponse) and as far as I know, I can't pass in `i` or `itemsToList` here:

```
exports.uniqueEntries = function(req, res){
    var query = req.params.query;
    console.log(query);
    db.products.distinct(query, function(err, results){
        if (err) {
            console.log("Lookup Error: " + err);
        } else{
            res.json({
                query:results  
            });
        }       
    });
}
```

Perhaps the issue is that by the time the `expressJS` lookup is finished, the three `for` loops have finished and `i == 2`. I have no idea why the console would log it as `i ==3` though, nor do I have any idea of how to block the loop to ensure the lookup finished before continuing on with the next `for` loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`$resource` methods](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource#Returns), including `get()`, are asynchronous. So, their callbacks will be called *later*. And, in this case, *later* is after the `for` loop has run to completion.

For any statements inside the callback, `i` will have already been incremented to `3`, which is why it's no longer `0`, `1`, or `2` for:

```
console.log('i = ' + i);
```

You can keep each value of `i` as it's incremented by creating a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) for it around the callback `function`:

```
function createCallback(itemsToList, i) {
  return function (data) {
      console.log(itemsToList); // Returns ["designer", "store", "Category"] x3
      console.log(itemsToList[i]); // Returns undefined, undefined, undefined
      console.log('i = ' + i); // Returns 3, 3, 3 (which is really odd, ideas?)

       $scope.uniqueLists[i] = data.query;
  };
}

for(var i = 0; i<itemsToList.length; i++){
  $scope.uniqueLists[itemsToList[i]] = [];  
  $scope.listItems.get({query:itemsToList[i]}, createCallback(itemsToList, i));
}
```

Another option, assuming `itemsToList` is an `Array`, can be to use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) in-place of the `for` loop as the iterator will be the closure:

```
itemsToList.forEach(function (item, i) {
  $scope.uniqueLists[item] = [];
  $scope.listItems.get({query:item}, function(data){ 
    console.log(itemsToList);
    console.log(itemsToList[i]);
    console.log('i = ' + i);

    $scope.uniqueLists[i] = data.query;
  });
});
```

Comment: Fantastic, that's done it. Cheers, I'm new to `async` and this really helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When you take a look at the jQuery documentation(http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), you'll find that $.get is short for:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success,
    dataType: dataType
});
```

The async propery of an ajax call is set to true by default.. (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) So change the get request for an ajax call with the property async set to false, i think that is the problem here.

Comment: In this case, `.get()` isn't referring to `jQuery.get()`. AngularJS `$resource`s [have their own `.get()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource#Returns).

Comment: Ok, well i still think its a sync/async problem by the sound of it.. Try to find a workaround within AngularJS or go for the jQuery.ajax().

Comment: I'm not using jQuery here at all.