# How to loop through eq(i) with variating i?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

I have multiple `<div class='drop'>` with jQuery `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()` attached to them. I would like to use some kind of loop to determine which one of the trigger `<span class='more'>` was clicked and `.slideDown()` the corresponding `<div>`. Here's what I've got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=0;
    $('.more').eq(i).click(function(){
        $('.drop').eq(i).slideDown(800) && $('.more').eq(i).hide(300);
    });
    $(".less").eq(i).click(function(){
        $(".drop").eq(i).slideUp(800) && $(".more").eq(i).show(500);
    });
});
```

It works as long as I define `i` and don't put it in a loop. As soon as it's looped like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i=0; i<$('.drop').length; i++){
        $('.more').eq(i).click(function(){
            $('.drop').eq(i).slideDown(800) && $('.more').eq(i).hide(300);
        });
        $(".less").eq(i).click(function(){
            $(".drop").eq(i).slideUp(800) && $(".more").eq(i).show(500);};
        });
    };
});
```

It stops working. What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure if it is THE problem, but you have a semicolon after the closing bracket of the for loop. Get rid of that.

Comment: @derstrom8 That doesn't cause an error. It's just an empty statement.

Comment: Your code is a mess. Fix your indentation before posting. And why are you using `&&` before executing the `$(".more").eq(...` part? It serves absolutely no purpose.

Comment: Dup of a problem posted about multiple times per day.  See [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop/11488129#11488129) for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following segment of code:

```
for(var i=0; i<$('.drop').length; i++){
  $('.more').eq(i).click(function(){
    $('.drop').eq(i).slideDown(800) && $('.more').eq(i).hide(300);
  });
}
```

When does that anonymous function get called? When one of the `.more` elements is clicked. 
What is the value of `i` at that point? The loop has finished by the time the element is clicked, so `i === $('.drop').length`.

So when the anonymous function is called, it's like executing the function:

```
function(){
    var i = $('.drop').length;
    $('.drop').eq(i).slideDown(800) && $('.more').eq(i).hide(300);
}
```

and it's pretty clear that `$('.drop').eq($('.drop').length)` isn't very useful.

You could fix it by creating a new function with a locally scoped copy of `i` at each iteration:

```
for(var i=0; i<$('.drop').length; i++){
  $('.more').eq(i).click(function(i) {
    return function(){
      $('.drop').eq(i).slideDown(800) && $('.more').eq(i).hide(300);
    };
  }(i));
}
```

However if all your elements with that class belong to some subtree of the DOM, there is probably a better way using event delegation. Bind to the click handler of the parent of that subtree and then handle it there and use `e.target` to determine which element was clicked. [There is an example of that here](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the [wrong use of a closure variable in a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake), in this case there is no need to use a loop.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $drops = $('.drop');
    var $mores = $('.more').click(function () {
        $drops.eq($mores.index(this)).slideDown(800) && $(this).hide(300);
    })
});
```