# Why is only the last object being assigned the onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to assign an onclick function to different types of items. So, within a for loop I have `if(invType[i] != "empty")` within that if statement I have

```
if(invType[i] == "usable"){
    document.getElementById(i).onclick = function(i){ return function(){useItem(invName[i],i)}; }(i);
}
if(invType[i] == "equipment"){
    document.getElementById(i).onclick = function(i){ return function(){equipItem(invName[i],i)}; }(i);
}
```

only the last non-`"empty"` item is getting assigned the onclick function, and I have no clue why. I need it to assign the onclick to every `"usable"` or `"equipment"` not just the last one.

Comment: Because by the time your `for` loop has completed, `i` is setting at one past the last value of the `for` loop and that's the value that `i` has some time in the future when you `onclick` handler is actually called.  This is a duplicate question of many previous answers.  I will try to find one of those dups.

Comment: Also see this answer: [Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop/11488129#11488129).