# Function in for loop behaves like a closure

Tags: javascript, loops, closures

I've been studying closures lately and beginning to get a hang of it, i understood from contents online and from my former question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981274/understanding-closures) that closures are created when a function is created inside another function (Don't know if this is the only condition for closure to exist). I decided to experiment more on this and these set of code got me confused, i didn't expect the output.

```
var f = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  f[i] = function(){
    console.log("Number " + i);
   }
};

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    f[i]();
}

//Actual Output
//Number 0
//Number 1
//Number 2

//Expected output
//Number 3
//Number 3
//Number 3
```

I think i should also mention that when i replaced the second loop with `Function.forEach` like this

```
f.forEach(function(i){
  i();
});
```

it printed the expected output. What am i missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are redefining the `i` variable.  With variable hoisting, your code is interpreted as:

```
var f = [];
var i;

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  f[i] = function(){
    console.log("Number " + i);
   }
};

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    // `i` is set back to 0 -> 3
    f[i]();
}
```

When you switch it with the `forEach` loop, you don't change the `i` variable and your closed over function works as expected.

If you want to continue to use a native `for`, just change `var i` to `var j`.

Comment: I was thinking the scope of i in the first loop should end with the closing brace of the loop, i guess JavaScript is a lot different from Java after all

Comment: JavaScript didn't get block scoping until recently with the `let` and `const` keywords.  You can use `let` in your `for` loops for the expected result once it's implemented everywhere, or if you transpile your code.