# QUnit.test running in a for loop

Tags: javascript, qunit

I was trying to do some code refactoring for QUnit tests. I used a json array TestCaseSource to store test case's input and expected output, and coded like this,

```
var data = TestCaseSource.data;

for (var i in data) {
    console.log(data[i]);
    QUnit.test(data[i].TestCaseName, function () {
        DoProcess(data[i].TestCaseName, "", data[i]);
    });
}
```

With this code, I could only have the first and last test case run. All the cases in the middle were omitted by QUnit. If I removed the for loop, and hard coded QUnit.test like,

```
    QUnit.test('TestCaseName1', function () {
        DoProcess('TestCaseName1', "", TestCaseSource.data[0]);
    });
    QUnit.test('TestCaseName2', function () {
        DoProcess('TestCaseName2', "", TestCaseSource.data[1]);
    });
    ...
```

Everything was fine then. Why the for loop was not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my answer in [Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop) . As it says in this very nice post:

> You have to freeze the value of i by passing it into a function
>   somewhere so it's value exists uniquely for each iteration of the loop
>   in a function closure. Otherwise, all asynch callbacks will just see
>   the value of i at the end of the loop which is the value it has when
>   they execute their callbacks (sometime later when the loop has
>   finished), not each their own value.