# For loop in Async Programming

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, instagram-api, asynccallback

```
userId = ['123', '456'];
userName = ['aaa', 'bbb'];
for (var j = 0; j < userId.length; j++) {
            Instagram.otherUserMedia(userId[j], function (response) {
                $('#otherInfo').append('<h2>' + userName[j] + '</h2>');
                for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                    $('#otherInfo').append('<img src="' + response.data[i].images.thumbnail.url + '" />');
                }
            });
        }
```

In this code snippet, I need to show corresponding `userName` with the output images from `response`. But when I execute this code, value of `j` increments till `userId.length` and then enters the callback.
So, when I want to show the `userName[j]` it says `j` is `undefined` because it has loop through every value in `userId`.
I want to get corresponding `userName` for every `userId`'s `response`.

Comment: Use the array's `forEach` method instead.

Comment: There are a zillion dups of this.  Here's another one [Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop/11488129#11488129)

Answer (score 2):

It'a problem related to JavaScript Closure.

A following demo could be one of the solutions;

```js
userId = ['123', '456'];
userName = ['aaa', 'bbb'];
for (var j = 0; j < userId.length; j++) {
  Instagram.otherUserMedia(userId[j], (function(index) {
    return function(response) {
      $('#otherInfo').append('<h2>' + userName[index] + '</h2>');
      for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
        $('#otherInfo').append('<img src="' + response.data[i].images.thumbnail.url + '" />');
      };
    }
  }(j)));
}
```

You may want to check resources like following:
[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)
[Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)
[Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Comment: It worked.
Thank you!