# Aggregate match pipeline not equal to in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I am working on an aggregate pipeline for MongoDB, and I am trying to retrieve items where the user is not equal to a variable.

For some reason, I couldn't make it work. I tried to use `$not`, `$ne` and `$nin` in different possible way but can't make it to work.

This is how it looks like:

Data sample:

```
[{
    "_id": { "$oid": "565674e2e4b030fba33d8fdc" },
    "user": { "$oid": "565674832b85ce78732b7529" }
}, {
    "_id": { "$oid": "565674e2e4b030fba33d8fdc" },
    "user": { "$oid": "565674832b85ce78732b7529" }
}, {
    "_id": { "$oid": "565674e2e4b030fba33d8fdc" },
    "user": { "$oid": "56f9dfc5cc03ec883f7675d0" }
}]
```

Pipeline sample (simplified for this question):

Where `req.query.user.id = "565674832b85ce78732b7529"`

```
collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            user: {
                $nin: [ req.query.user.id ],
            }
        }
    }
]
```

This should return only the last item.

Do you have any idea how to retrieve the data that doesn't match the user?

Thanks

**Edit:** 
The following doesn't work either:

```
collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            'user.$oid': {
                $nin: [ req.query.user.id ],
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

I also tried with `ObjectID()` and mongodb complains: `[MongoError: Argument must be a string]`

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

// Waterline syntax here
MyCollection.native(function (err, collection) {
    collection.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                'user': {
                    $nin: [ ObjectID(req.query.user.id) ],
                }
            }
        }
    ], function (err, result) {
        console.log(err, result);
    });
});
```

But this line works in the shell:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match:{"user":{"$nin":[ObjectId("565674832b85ce78732b7529")]}}}])
```

Comment: You are missing "$oid" in the query. So try "user.$oid" instead of user in the used query.

Comment: Are you using some kind of custom `_id` fields, not Mongo's `ObjectId` instances?
Usually you have to `$nin: [ ObjectId(req.query.user.id) ]` when querying against `ObjectId`-like fields.

Comment: I use `waterline` (http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm) which automatically generate those `id`.

Comment: mongodb does not allow key name start with $ how you save the data with "$oid"?

Comment: Actually, it's not waterline which creates this format. I just found out it's because I use mLab which use MongoDB is strict mode: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38603529/argument-must-be-a-string-in-nodejs

Comment: @4J41 OMG this works!!!! You should add this to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38606392/1611791), you can change

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb'). ObjectID;
```

to

```
var ObjectId = require('sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb').ObjectID;
```