# TypeError: Argument must be a string at TypeError (native) at Buffer.write (buffer.js:771:21)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a very simple function that finds all booking collections. but it give an error message. although, i am passing a string value into **new Object Id** to match the **MongoDB** format. it show an error message *argument must be a string value.* if have checked with console it shows a string. if i am use like this.

```
var clientID = new ObjectID(req.body.clientID).toString();
```

it will remove error but still find not found any collection and return empty [] array.

```js
    app.post('/api/someFunction' ,function(req,response)
    {
        var clientID = new ObjectID(req.body.clientID);
        db=req.db;
        var collection=db.get('bookingscollections');
        collection.find
        (
            {'serviceProviderID':clientID},function(error,bookings)
            {
                if(error){
                    console.log(error); // Error
                    response.send(error)
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log(bookings); // if bookings
                    response.send(bookings);
                }
            }
        );
    });
```

> TypeError: Argument must be a string
>       at TypeError (native)
>       at Buffer.write (buffer.js:771:21)

i want to fetch from mongoDB which is mention below.

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("59c25185a32f0b188408fc97"),
    "serviceProviderID" : ObjectId("59afe299f62d6bec1a617bed"),
    "serviceBookerID" : "59b92c791602cf8018f2169b",
    "serviceBookerName" : "uemr Rasheed",
    "visitorPhone" : "+99(99)9999-9999"
}
```

Comment: FYI you may be missing a `var` in front of `db`: `var db=req.db;`

Comment: Same result after using var db = req.db @msanford

Comment: @alexmac you are right. I deleted my erroneous answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Argument must be a string in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38603529/argument-must-be-a-string-in-nodejs)