# Get data asynchronously JavaScript within for loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, prototypejs

I have this function

```
function add_cnh(arr_clelem){

  var id=arr_clelem.getElementsByClassName("present")[0].id;
  var date=arr_clelem.getElementsByClassName("present")[0].getAttribute('date');
  var tt_entry= arr_clelem.getElementsByClassName("present")[0].getAttribute('tt_entry'); 


//new Ajax.Updater('register', '/some_url', { method: 'get' });

new Ajax.Request('/attendances/new',
{
    parameters:'id='+id+'&date='+date+'&timetable_entry='+tt_entry+'&subject_id='+subject_id,
    asynchronous:true,
    evalScripts:true,
    method:'get'
 /*onSuccess: function(transport) {
var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
alert("Success! \n\n" + response);
}*/

}
)
var ret=modal_data;
  // $$('.MB_close').invoke('observe', 'click', _deinit);
return ret;

}
```

This function takes html-elements-object as an argument and basically render a modal-box and that modal box contain a form -elements which i need to store inside an array. The variable modal_data contains the elements which I require and its a global variable define in another file.

My problem is
This is a very old project using many JavaScript frameworks and libraries which  date back to 2006 the library responsible for opening the model box itself is deprecated as can be seen [here](https://github.com/okonet/modalbox/blob/master/modalbox.js)

And somehow I don't want to get into server side so I am using a for loop something like this

```
for(var i=0; i<arr_of_elements.length, i++)
{
   my_arrvar[i]=add_cnh(arr_of_elements[i]);
}
```

Now with each itteration since I want the modal box to get closed and store the data within 'my_arrvar' which is somehow not possible as the call is asynchronous in nature and I've used closures and callbacks but no success. I don't want to use any sort of timer. So this is how it goes

Call the function and get data for each call and remove the modal box by id.

Also can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11488129/3471519) be used somehow and if then how?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to pass in ajax request `asynchronous:false` instead of true. Otherwise its not possible by another way.

**Other Way using jQuery**

The easiest way is to use the .ajaxStop() event handler:

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  // place code to be executed on completion of last outstanding ajax call here
});

See [jQuery Event handler](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/)

Comment: But it will freeze the brwser. Are you sure there is no other way?

Comment: however asynchronous:false seems not to work as this was the first thing ive tried

Comment: can  this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11488129/3471519 be used somehow with the existing code?

Comment: I have modified answer, for alternate way using jquery ajax event handler

Comment: forgot to mention. Jquery v 1.3 is used in this project

Comment: thanks to marks as correct, dont forget to up vote please.. thanks in advance