# Google Maps Geocode Not Working in For Loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, geocoding

**Edit - I have fixed this by using `forEach` rather than a for loop since the items are pulled from an array**

I'm using this code to retrieve the latitude and longitude of a given address to be used with leaflet.js.

```
markers = [
        {
            "name": "Tom David",   
            "address": "Karachi, Pakistan",
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anguilla"
        },
        {
            "name": "Bob Thomas",
            "address": "London, Canada",
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan"
        },
        {
            "name": "Bob Mike",
            "address": "Paris, FR",
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan"
        }
];


for ( var i=0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {

            geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({'address': markers[i].address}, function(results, status) {

            L.marker([results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()]).bindTooltip(markers[i].address).addTo(map); 


            });               

}
```

The problem lies with `bindToolTip(markers[i].address)` as it seems to 'break' the code though when using a string name (like `"Hello"`), it works just fine.

This is due to the loop not working as intended to after the `new google.maps.geocoder()` part. I have tried using `alert(i)` below the said code, and it just iterates the number `12` three times for some reason.

When it is placed above the `geocoder()` part, it works correctly and iterates `0`, `1`, and `2`.

I would really appreciate any help with this.

**Overall**

- Retrieve the address from the array based on the current `i` value in the for loop
- Display the address retrieved in the `bindTooltip()` part to be displayed as a tooltip value within the map.

**Edit**

[Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop) This question has been marked as a duplicate of the link shown, though I am unsure of how the answers provided could be used in my own. Could someone help me out with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop)

Comment: @Hodrobond Thanks for the link, though I am really unsure of how to implement that in the case of my code? Could you help me out with this?

Comment: [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)s might be the easiest to implement depending on the scenario. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/L7ce4xyL/) is a simple example. Basically create an [anonymous function](http://helephant.com/2008/08/23/javascript-anonymous-functions/) and pass `i` in.

Comment: Try something along the lines of `for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
 (function(i){
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': markers[i].address
  }, function(results, status) {

    L.marker([results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()]).bindTooltip(markers[i].address).addTo(map);  
  })(i)
  });
}`

Comment: @Hodrobond Thanks a lot for the code! For some reason, the values don't get displayed this time though. I've tried changing `markers[i]` to a normal string to test it out and the markers don't even get placed on the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised I can use `forEach` rather than having to use a for loop, since the data is pulled from an array