# How to change constant to variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

This is the full code using constant number and it works.
( If I click 'text 2' the box is moved.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.myDIV {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: coral;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="text">text 1</div>
    <div class="myDIV"></div>
<div class="text">text 2</div>
    <div class="myDIV"></div>

<script>
var texts = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("myDIV");
        texts[1].onclick = function(e){
        boxes[1].style.top = "100px";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But after I changed the constant '1' to variable'i' in the javascript, it doesn't work. I think there is some error in my code, but I don't know what it is.

```
<script>
var texts = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("myDIV");
    for(var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++)
        texts[i].onclick = function(e){
        boxes[1].style.top = "100px";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Also use `i` in `boxes`

Comment: Related // [Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop) // [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: What purpose you wrote code like this?

Comment: I put it into a JSFiddle and it worked fine: https://jsfiddle.net/1bmuo05k/

Comment: Thank you Stephen. It didn't work to me, so I thought my code have some error. I should restart my browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more idiomatic way to do this is with `forEach().` It prevents the problems of variables in for loops.

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gr8jzkdr/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.myDIV {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: coral;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="text">text 1</div>
    <div class="myDIV"></div>
<div class="text">text 2</div>
    <div class="myDIV"></div>
<div class="text">text 3</div>
    <div class="myDIV"></div>
<div class="text">text 4</div>
    <div class="myDIV"></div>

<script>
var texts = document.querySelectorAll(".text");
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".myDIV");
texts.forEach(function(element, index) {
    element.onclick = function(e){
        boxes[index].style.left = "100px";

    }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any need of `e` variable in the onclick function?

Comment: No, the event will be passed to the function, but it isn't being used in this case.

Comment: What I want to do finally is that when I mousemove on the text, each image follows the mouse pointer.(I should do this without <span>tag) so I revised my code accroding to your helpful answer. and it has problem again. 
here’s a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/technic/agze4Lgh/#&togetherjs=qJLgL5Orjz

Comment: Your code has a typo that is throwing an error -- you have `boxed` when you want `boxes`. To make this work you need to add units such as: `boxes[index].style.top = y+"px"`

Answer (score 1):

You need [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), plus I think you've forgotten to put a `i` index in your`boxes[]` array.

```js
var texts = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("myDIV");

for(var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++)
{
  (function(){
    var ci = i;
    texts[ci].onclick = function(e){
    boxes[ci].style.top = "100px";}
   })();
}
```

```css
.myDIV {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: coral;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">text 1</div>
    <div class="myDIV"></div>
<div class="text">text 2</div>
    <div class="myDIV"></div>
```