# ajax inside for loop doesn't run in sequence

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have ajax requests in my for loop and I am trying to print the value of iteration index 'i' in each iteration. I am using a wrapper function(which is suggested in many posts) in for loop to execute the ajax. But when I print the value of console, it gets printed in random manner. And each time I run the for loop, it is different.

Here is my for loop and wrapper function

```
 get_process_status(){                  //new

        for(var i=0; i<this.state.current_auto_video_jobs_urls.length; i++){
            this.get_auto_video_jobs_array(i)
        }
    }

//wrapper function

    get_auto_video_jobs_array(i){
        var that = this;
        var settings_3 = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": that.state.current_auto_video_jobs_urls[i],
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                Authorization: "Token " + that.props.token_Reducer.token
            },
            success: function (response, textStatus, jQxhr) {
                console.log("success")
                console.log("value of i is " + i)
            },
        }

        $.ajax(settings_3).done((response) => {
            auto_video_jobs_array.push(response)
            if(i == that.state.current_auto_video_jobs_urls.length -1 ){
                console.log("i reached last value")
                that.setState({current_auto_video_jobs: auto_video_jobs_array})
                console.log("current jobs are" + that.state.current_auto_video_jobs)
            }
        });
    }
```

Console output

[image]

You can see in 2 times, value of i printed was on different sequence. Why can't it be just 0 to 9 in sequence every time loop runs?

Comment: The “A” in Ajax is for “asynchronous “...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop

Answer (score 0):

Because AJAX, as is name suggest (Asynchronous Javascript And XML), is **asynchronous**, meaning it will not run sequentially.
For your code to work you have to put the loop inside the `success` handler of the Ajax request