# promise.all().then not work

Tags: node.js, concurrency, es6-promise

I use promise.all to limit the number of concurrent visits,, but promise.all().then() not work ,flag always false ,why!!

```js
function getPage(singeUrl) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
   superagent.get(singeUrl)
    .set({'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36'})
    .charset('utf8')
    .end(function (err, sres) {
     if (err) throw err;
     utils.singleRequest(sres,db)
    });
   resolve('resolve=='+singeUrl)
  })
 }
 let flag = true;
 pages.forEach((item) => {
  if(flag){
   flag = false;
   let promises = item.map(function (url) {
    return getPage(url);
   });
   Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
    flag = true;
   })
  }
 })
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

The problem is that because you are looping through a multidimensional array of promises, and because the condition `if (flag)` relies on flag being true to execute any code in `pages.forEach()`, the loop stops executing any code after the first iteration. This is because `Promise.All()` is an asynchronous operation. By the time the promises created from `pages[0]` have resolved (which also sets `flag` to `true`), the iteration has already finished its first loop, but `flag` is still set to `false`.

You could solve this problem by flattening the multi-dimensional array of promises, so that `Promise.all()` will await for all of the promises at once instead of iterating through them.

I made a few changes to your code to demonstrate this:

```
let pages = [];
pages.push(['one', 'two']);
pages.push(['three', 'four']);
pages.push(['five', 'six']);

let getPage = function(singeUrl) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    resolve('resolve=='+singeUrl)
    if(!singleUrl) reject('No input');
  });
}

let flag = true;

pages.forEach((item) => {
  if(flag){
    flag = false;
    let promises = item.map(function (url) {

      // You will notice in the output at the bottom, that
      // only the array pages[0] have been executed by Promise.all()

      console.log('url: ', url);

      return getPage(url);
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then((res) => {

      // The log statements below are executed last

      console.log('flag1 in promise: ', flag);

      flag = true;

      console.log('flag2 in promise: ', flag);
    });
  }
});

// This statement executes before flag
// is set to true
console.log('final flag: ', flag);
```

output:

```
url:  one
url:  two
final flag:  false
flag1 in promise:  false
flag2 in promise:  true
```

Comment: pages indeed  is a multi-dimensional array

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem. I have edited my solution, hopefully that works for you.