# AngularJS TypeError: updateCompany is undefined

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

Resource:

This is the Resource I use for the Update function. I am unable to invoke the Update method in my Resource (written in Java)

```
c.adminCompaniesResource = $resource("api/admin/companies/:id",{"id":"@id"},{
  "updateCompany": {method:"PUT"}
});
```

Update Company Function:

First I put all companies in an Array and then I'm trying to invoke an update action on a specific company in the Array

Problem with line: "updateCompany.$updateCompany(company, function() {"

TypeError: updateCompany is undefined

```
c.allCompanies = [];

c.updateCompanyForm = function(company) {
  const updateCompany = company;
  c.allCompanies = c.adminAllCompaniesResource.query(c.companyFields, function() {
    c.allCompanies.forEach(function(company){
      if (c.companyFields.id == company.id) {
        company.id = c.companyFields.id;
        company.password = c.companyFields.password;
        company.email = c.companyFields.email;
        updateCompany.$updateCompany(company, function() { 
          //problem here
          c.companyFields.id = company.id;
          c.companyFields.compName = company.compName;
          c.companyFields.password = company.password;
          c.companyFields.email = company.email;
          c.updateCompanyTableDiv = true;
          c.updateCompanyExceptionDiv = false;
          }, function() {
            c.error("Request could not be completed");
            c.updateCompanyExceptionDiv = true;
            c.updateCompanyTableDiv = false;
          });
        }
      })
   }, function() {
        c.error("Request could not be completed")
        c.getAllCompaniesExceptionDiv = true;
        c.getAllCompaniesTableDiv = false;
   });
}
```

Comment: It looks a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop) question

Comment: I looked at what you suggested, My code already contains one of the presented solutions: forEach loop. I don't believe what you suggested is similar to my problem. Can you please review my post again? I am stuck on this for more than two weeks

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no problem with your code. The error message is pretty much for the resolution of the issue. The call to function `c.updateCompanyForm()` is sending the `undefined` value to it. Which leads to failure. If you can provide the complete code fragment, than it is possible to find the source of error.

I tried to mock up your code with dummy function.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script>
         var c = {
            companyFields: {
                id: 10
            },
            adminAllCompaniesResource: {
                query: function(fields, callback) {
                    callback();
                    return [{
                        id: 10
                    }];
                }
            }
         };
         c.allCompanies = [
            {id: 10}
         ];

         c.updateCompanyForm = function(company) {
           const updateCompany = company;
           c.allCompanies = c.adminAllCompaniesResource.query(c.companyFields, function() {
             c.allCompanies.forEach(function(company){
               if (c.companyFields.id == company.id) {
                 company.id = c.companyFields.id;
                 company.password = c.companyFields.password;
                 company.email = c.companyFields.email;
                 updateCompany.$updateCompany(company, function() { 
                   //problem here
                   c.companyFields.id = company.id;
                   c.companyFields.compName = company.compName;
                   c.companyFields.password = company.password;
                   c.companyFields.email = company.email;
                   c.updateCompanyTableDiv = true;
                   c.updateCompanyExceptionDiv = false;
                   }, function() {
                     c.error("Request could not be completed");
                     c.updateCompanyExceptionDiv = true;
                     c.updateCompanyTableDiv = false;
                   });
                 }
               })
            }, function() {
                 c.error("Request could not be completed")
                 c.getAllCompaniesExceptionDiv = true;
                 c.getAllCompaniesTableDiv = false;
            });
         }
         //Test 1: This should show message "Here"
         c.updateCompanyForm({id: 10, $updateCompany: function() {alert('Here')}});
         //Test 2: This will produce error
         c.updateCompanyForm(undefined);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Hopefully this gives you the idea from where the issue started propagation.