# Node.js for loop using previous values?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently, I am trying to get the md5 of every value in array. Essentially, I loop over every value and then hash it, as such.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
  function userHash(userIDstring) {
    return crypto.createHash('md5').update(userIDstring).digest('hex');
  }

  for (var userID in watching) {
    refPromises.push(admin.database().ref('notifications/'+ userID).once('value', (snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
        const userHashString =  userHash(userID)
        console.log(userHashString.toUpperCase() + "this is the hashed string")
        if (userHashString.toUpperCase() === poster){
            return console.log("this is the poster")
        }
        else {
            ..
        }
    }
    else {
        return null
    }
      })
    )}
```

However, this leads to two problems. The first is that I am receiving the error warning "Don't make functions within a loop". The second problem is that the hashes are all returning the same. Even though every `userID` is unique, the userHashString is printing out the same value for every user in the console log, as if it is just using the first userID, getting the hash for it, and then printing it out every time.

Update LATEST :

```
exports.sendNotificationForPost = functions.firestore
    .document('posts/{posts}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const value = snap.data()
      const watching = value.watchedBy
      const poster = value.poster
      const postContentNotification = value.post
      const refPromises = []
      var crypto = require('crypto');
      function userHash(userIDstring) {
        return crypto.createHash('md5').update(userIDstring).digest('hex');
      }

      for (let userID in watching) {
        refPromises.push(admin.database().ref('notifications/'+ userID).once('value', (snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
            const userHashString =  userHash(userID)

            if (userHashString.toUpperCase() === poster){
                return null
            }
            else {

                const payload = {
                    notification: {
                        title: "Someone posted something!",
                        body: postContentNotification,
                        sound: 'default'
                    }
                };

                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(snapshot.val(), payload)
            }
        }
        else {
            return null
        }
          })
        )}
        return Promise.all(refPromises);
    });
```

Comment: What data type is the `watching` variable.  Is it an array of userIDs?  Or an object with userIDs as properties or values?

Comment: It is an array of user IDs

Comment: Well, then `for (var userID in watching)` doesn't iterate your array either.  That iterates properties on the object, not array elements.  Never use `for/in` to iterate array elements.  Never.  In modern node.js, use `for/of`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple issues going on here.  First, you have a non-blocking asynchronous operation inside a loop.  You need to fully understand what that means.  Your loop runs to completion starting a bunch of non-blocking, asynchronous operations.  Then, when the loop finished, one by one your asynchronous operations finish.  That is why your loop variable `userID` is sitting on the wrong value.  It's on the terminal value when all your async callbacks get called.

You can see a discussion of the loop variable issue here with several options for addressing that:

[Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop/11488129#11488129)

Second, you also need a way to know when all your asynchronous operations are done.  It's kind of like you sent off 20 carrier pigeons with no idea when they will all bring you back some message (in any random order), so you need a way to know when all of them have come back.

To know when all your async operations are done, there are a bunch of different approaches.  The "modern design" and the future of the Javascript language would be to use promises to represent your asynchronous operations and to use `Promise.all()` to track them, keep the results in order, notify you when they are all done and propagate any error that might occur.

---

Here's a cleaned-up version of your code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

exports.sendNotificationForPost = functions.firestore.document('posts/{posts}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const value = snap.data();
    const watching = value.watchedBy;
    const poster = value.poster;
    const postContentNotification = value.post;

    function userHash(userIDstring) {
        return crypto.createHash('md5').update(userIDstring).digest('hex');
    }

    return Promise.all(Object.keys(watching).map(userID => {
        return admin.database().ref('notifications/' + userID).once('value').then(snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                const userHashString = userHash(userID);

                if (userHashString.toUpperCase() === poster) {
                    // user is same as poster, don't send to them
                    return {response: null, user: userID, poster: true};
                } else {
                    const payload = {
                        notification: {
                            title: "Someone posted something!",
                            body: postContentNotification,
                            sound: 'default'
                        }
                    };
                    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(snapshot.val(), payload).then(response => {
                        return {response, user: userID};
                    }).catch(err => {
                        console.log("err in sendToDevice", err);
                        // if you want further processing to stop if there's a sendToDevice error, then
                        // uncomment the throw err line and remove the lines after it.  
                        // Otherwise, the error is logged and returned, but then ignored 
                        // so other processing continues

                        // throw err

                        // when return value is an object with err property, caller can see
                        // that that particular sendToDevice failed, can see the userID and the error
                        return {err, user: userID};    
                    });
                }
            } else {
                return {response: null, user: userID};
            }
        });
    }));
});
```

Changes:

1. Move `require()` out of the loop.  No reason to call it multiple times.
2. Use `.map()` to collect the array of promises for `Promise.all()`.
3. Use `Object.keys()` to get an array of userIDs from the object keys so we can then use `.map()` on it.
4. Use `.then()` with `.once()`.
5. Log `sendToDevice()` error.
6. Use `Promise.all()` to track when all the promises are done
7. Make sure all promise return paths return an object with some common properties so the caller can get a full look at what happened for each user

Comment: I changed it to forEach, except doesn't refPromsises.push act as a waiting for the carrier pigeons, essentially? Because it waits for the promises, correct?

Comment: @RaimKhalil - `forEach()` will solve your loop iterator issue because it makes a unique function call and function parameter for each invocation of the loop.  What does `admin.database().ref('notifications/'+ userID).once('value', (snapshot) => {})` return?  Does it return a promise?  Usually, in modern interfaces that support both a callback and a promise, if you pass it a callback like you are, it will not also return a promise.

Comment: sorry, I did not include the returning of the promises. Is this the correct way to do so? (As in my updated answer)

Comment: Sorry for my confusion, I am very new to node.js. I'm not exactly sure what it returns -- in another question, someone replied that `You are both passing a callback to once() and using its returned promise. You should just choose one or the other, preferably just using its promise.`

Comment: @RaimKhalil - `return Promise.all(refPromises);` is the right idea if `refPromises` is actually an array of promises, but I don't think it is because you're passing a callback.  I'll add something to my answer to show you in a second.  Then then caller will have to use `.then()` on the return value from calling it.

Comment: really appreciate your help. One last thing, when I do forEach I get `watching.forEach is not a function
    at exports.sendNotificationForPost.functions.firestore.document.onCreate `

Comment: @RaimKhalil - Then, apparently `watching` is not an array.  You really need to now what type of data it is.

Comment: basically, I get the data from `.document('posts/{posts}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const value = snap.data()
      const watching = value.watchedBy`

Comment: @RaimKhalil - Sorry, but I don't know your database interface.

Comment: After research, it appears that .value returns an object representing the document. Then, value.watchedBy is a field of a JS property.

Comment: the problem with the hashes was fixed by changing it to let rather than var. However, I'm still not sure if I'm dealing with the promises correctly - although the function works as expected and there's no errors, I want to make sure I am using the best practices and implementing it correctly.

Comment: @RaimKhalil - The code in your question is not yet correct.  It won't be returning values in the promise.  If you can add your latest revision to the end of your question, I can take a look later this evening and offer suggestions.

Comment: @RaimKhalil - I added a "fixed up" version of your code to the end of my answer.

Comment: I can not overstate how much this has helped me, learning how to code better (catching errors and using promises) along with implementation for my app. I really appreciate your thorough response. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

These are not two problems: the warning you get is trying to help you solve the second problem you noticed.

And the problem is: in Javascript, only functions create separate scopes - every function you define inside a loop - uses the same scope. And that means they don't get their own copies of the relevant loop variables, they share a single reference (which, by the time the first promise is resolved, will be equal to the last element of the array).

Just replace `for` with `.forEach`.

Comment: If you're using a moderately recent version of Node, you should be able to depend on block scopes using `let` instead of `var` in the `for` loop.

Comment: @MarkMeyer .forEach will not work for objects, will it? So just replacing the var with let will fix it?