# can't figure Javascript loops

Tags: javascript

```
for(var x = 19; x <= 29; x = x + 1) {
  if(x < 29) {
    if(values[x]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      var file = $(`#${keys[x]}`)[0].files[0];
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onloadend = function () {
        values[x] = reader.result.slice(reader.result.indexOf(',')+1);
      };
    }
  } else {
     insertAll();
  }
}
```

the code above only returns the last file and skips all others because it takes time to finish so how do i make sure loop won't continue without finishing reading file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop)

Comment: Note: Usually people just do `++x` instead of the pointlessly long-form `x = x + 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use recursion instead of a loop, here is an example:

```
function recursion(x){
  if(x < 29) {
    if(values[x]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      var file = $(`#${keys[x]}`)[0].files[0];
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onloadend = function () {
        values[x] = reader.result.slice(reader.result.indexOf(',')+1);
        recursion(++x)
      };
    }
  } else {
     insertAll();
  }
}
recursion(19)
// You get here only after all the files are read.
```

The idea is to start reading the next file only after you finish reading the current one (*`recursion(...)` is called inside the `reader.onloadend` callback*)

Comment: This is a good start, but to make it a little more robust it might be worth expanding the number range into an array and pulling off the numbers with `pop` instead of cluttering it up with these magic numbers like `29`. Instead: `recursion([ 19, 20, 21, ... 29 ])` This is a minor difference but allows you to re-order, have holes in the sequence, etc.

Comment: This recursive approach requires 'extra overhead' linear time as the loading must be processed purely synchronously. That is, there is no option for the run-time to perform parallel IO.

Comment: @user2864740 So is most ways of using promises, like **FrankerZ's** solution for example. That is sequential as well.

Comment: @Titus I left him a comment too :D

Answer (score 2):

Recursion can get a little ugly. You should wrap them in promises, and use new es6 `await/async` syntax:

```
function readValues(filename) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      const file = $(`#${filename}`)[0].files[0];
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        resolve(reader.result.slice(reader.result.indexOf(',')+1));
      };
  });
}

async function main() {
    let results = {};

    for(let x = 19; x < 29; x++) {
      if(values[x]) {
        results[x] = await readValues(keys[x]);
      }
    }

    insertAll(results);
}

main();
```

For reading all the files at the same time, I recommend using `Promise.all`:

```
function readValues(filename) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      const file = $(`#${filename}`)[0].files[0];
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        resolve(reader.result.slice(reader.result.indexOf(',')+1));
      };
  });
}

async function main() {
  let promises = [];
  let results = {};

  for(let x = 19; x < 29; x++) {
    if(values[x]) {
      const task = readValues(keys[x])
                      // Assign the values in results
                      .then(res => results[x] = res);
      promises.push(task);
    }
  }

  await Promise.all(promises);

  // Results is now an object that you can use.
  insertAll(results);
}

main();
```

Comment: @user2864740 Updated my example with a `Promise.all` example.

Answer (score -1):

create other function to handle read file

```
for(var x = 19; x <= 29; x = x + 1) {
if(x < 29) {
  if(values[x]) {
    readData(x);
  }
} else {
   insertAll();
}
}

function readData(x){
var reader = new FileReader();
    var file = $(`#${keys[x]}`)[0].files[0];
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
      values[x] = reader.result.slice(reader.result.indexOf(',')+1);
    };
}
```