# Promise.Resolve is blocking UI

Tags: javascript, promise

I have added one button in UI. `onclick` of this button I am calling a function which is returning promise. This piece of code supposed to not block the UI but this is blocking the UI.

```
    <button onclick="block()">Click Me</button>

    const blockUI = () => {
        return Promise.resolve().then(_ =>{
           console.log('loop start');
           let i=0;
           while(i<10000000000) {
              i++;
           }
        return 'loop end'
    });
   }

 const block = ()=> {blockUI().then(d => {
    console.log(d);
 })}
```

How can I make this async?

Comment: Hm, the problem is that  intensive CPU  will bock the event loop hence the UI block.

Comment: @EugenSunic that means I can't make it asyncrhonous?

Comment: Yes I believe your UI will remain blocked under intensive CPU work. Let's see if an expert can give a better answer if I may be wrong...

Comment: Your code is actually synchronous. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54478255/why-is-my-infinite-loop-blocking-when-it-is-in-an-async-function).

Comment: @EugenSunic this thing making my understanding on Promises incorrect. This was supposed to be run async. If it is blocking the UI then there is no use of promises. It just behaving like normal synchronous code.

Comment: @Dalvik Yes. Promises do not *make* anything asynchronous themselves, they're only a tool that makes working with asynchronous things easier. And they definitely do not make CPU-intensive code run in parallel or something, that's what workers are meant for.

Comment: async != concurrent