# How to make a normal java script function asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Firstly The code below prints the value from the `call()` function which it returns though it takes some time to execute, then it prints the next line.

But I want to make it async behavior so that it first outputs the last line(which execution time is less) than the previous (higher exec time). How can I do that?

```js
function call() {
  let counter = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 40000; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 50000; j++) {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  return counter;
}
console.log(call());
console.log('loading ... ');
```

Comment: No matter the order, neither will log until `call` has finished running.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If it's just to get a different output order it would be much easier to just swap the lines. What else do you hope to achieve with that?

Comment: duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54478255/why-is-my-infinite-loop-blocking-when-it-is-in-an-async-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop)

Answer (score -1):

By adding the key word `async` before the fonction so it becomes

```
async function call(){...}
```

i hope it will helps

Comment: Please show an example

Comment: That alone is not enough.

Answer (score -1):

### Asynchronous functions

Asynchronous functions are built on top of promises. They allow a more convenient use of Promises. Asynchronous functions have the following properties:

- `async` before a function declaration/expression turns the function into an async function. As the name suggests async function are executed asynchronously.
- **An async function always returns a promise**. It wraps any returned value in `Promise.resolve(returnval)`. However, when an uncaught error is thrown inside the async function it wraps the return value in `Promise.catch(returnval)`.
- Inside async functions you can use the `await` keyword which can be used before any promise. `await` makes JS code execution stop until the promise is settled. i.e. The promise has to be either fulfilled or rejected until any further code inside the async function is executed.
- `await` either returns the value of the fulfilled promise, or throws an error in the case of a rejected promise. We can use regular try-catch to catch the error.

Let's clarify this with some examples:

### Example1:

```js
const randomProm = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        resolve("Succes");
    } else {
        reject("Failure");
    }
});

// async keyword creates an async function which returns a promise 
async function ansyncExample() {

    try {
        const outcome = await randomProm;
        console.log(outcome);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    // This return value is wrapped in a promise
    return 'AsyncReturnVal';
}

// ansyncExample() returns a promise, we can call its corresponding then method
ansyncExample().then((value) => {
    console.log(value);
});

console.log('I get executed before the async code because this is synchronous');
```

Comment: *"As the name suggests async function are executed asynchronously."* That's not true. `async` implies two things: The function returns a promise and you can use `await` inside the function to suspend execution. `async` alone doesn't mean that the function is executed asynchronously. Just run `(async function() { console.log('inside'); return 42; }()); console.log('after');`. Or to put in another words: Everything until the first `await` expression is executed synchronously.