# Jasmine: looped tests fail to run if asynchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jasmine, protractor

I'm working on implementing a test that reads a list of files from a given directory. The list is then checked against a `Map` object that uses filenames as keys. If a match is found I want to execute some tests, if not skip the file and move on to the next one.

I have the test working if I just grab one object from the Map but it fails when I try to loop. I want to run tests by looping over multiple files.

It only seems to be a problem if I have async calls in my tests. Using a completely synchronous loop I can get it to run just fine. Here is an example of the synchronous loop *(I realize this is a very contrived example but it works as expected)*:

```
describe('a test', () => {
  const list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

  const test = (x) => {
    describe(`should run ${x}`, () => {
        beforeAll(async () => {
            console.log('beforeAll');
        });

        beforeEach(async () => {
            console.log('beforeEach');
        });

        for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          it(`should log iteration ${i}`, async () => {
            console.log(x, i);

            expect(i).toBeTruthy();
          });
        }
    });
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    test(list[i]);
  }
});
```

The output from the above snippet suggests that it runs just fine:
[image]

This same pattern does not work if it is asynchronous though. In fact, the nested describe in `test` isn't even running as far as I can tell. I logged the `project` variable to the console so I could see that it was getting called but the `logging in...` statement in the `beforeAll` isn't getting executed at all. It seems like it's just skipping right over it. How do I make this work with `async/await`?

```
describe('Import Project', () => {
  const _page = new PageFactory();
  const utils = new Utils();
  const projPath = browser.params.projPath;

  let projectGuid: string;

  const test = (project) => {
    describe(`importing ${project.name}`, () => {
        beforeAll(async () => {
            console.log('logging in...'); //not getting executed for some reason
            await _page.loginPage.login(browser.params.username, browser.params.password);

            // import
            await _page.projectsPage.importProject(projectPath + project.filename)
                .withImportType(project.importType)
                .withProjectName(project.projectName)
                .inEnvironment(project.environment)
                .import();

            projectGuid = await utils.extractGuid();
        });

        afterEach(async () => {
            await _page.designerPage.navigateTo(projectGuid);
        });

        for(let i = 0; i < project.operations.length; i++) {
            const operation = project.operations[i];

            it(`should run ${operation.name} successfully`, async () => {
                await runOperation(operation.name);

                const status = await _page.operationLogsPage.getStatus(operation.outcomeTarget);
                expect(status).toEqual(operation.expectedStatus);
            });
        }
    });
  }

  utils.getProjects().then(projects => {
    // projects is a string[] of filenames
    // that are returned using fs.readdir()
    for (let i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
        const myProject = projectMap.get(projects[i]);

        if (myProject) {
            test(myProject);
        }
    }
  });
});
```

The output from this is just `Executed 0 of 0 specs SUCCESS in 0.003 sec.`

I don't understand how this would be any different than manually writing out all these nested describe blocks. If I wrote each one out it would work just fine but for some reason in a loop it doesn't want to work. Any ideas?

Comment: For the record, I also tried awaiting `test`. That did not work either.

Comment: for loop does not wait assync routine inside it. this is related to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop

Comment: That answer suggests several things that don't work. `.forEach(async p => { // do stuff }` fails with the same result. Putting the loop inside an async function like `async function something() { for(..) { await test(project) } }` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to get this to work the way I wanted. Instead I decided to use node's `child_process.execSync` and looped through each file that way. It's not ideal but it works. Takes a bit longer since each file I want to run tests on creates a new session but I'm tired of trying to make it work the other way.

I'm running the script using `node ./path/to/test.js --baseUrl=http://<myUrl>`

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
fs.readdir(projectsPath, (err, files) => {
  if (err) {
    throw new Error('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
  }

  let i = 0;

  const next = () => {
    if (i < files.length) {
        const file = files[i];
        console.log('running tests on:', file);            

        const runCmd = `nodenv --exec "yarn run e2e:all ${baseUrl} --params.projectToImport=${file} --suite import_projects"`            

        // exec
        try {
            execSync(runCmd, { cwd: workingDir, stdio: 'inherit' },
                (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                    if (error) {
                        console.error(error);
                        return;
                    }

                    console.log(stdout);
                });
        } catch (err) {
            if (err.stderr) {
                console.log('stderr:', err.stderr.toString());
            }
        }

        // next iteration
        i++;
        next();
      }
  }

  next();
});
```