# Nodejs Async db.end() called too soon

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a function that uses a `for` loop to insert data in database. But db.end() is being called before the loop is finished executing. I've also tried to convert `db.query` into a `promise` using the `util` library, and same thing happens. What do i need to change to ensure that `.end()` doesn't get called until the `for` loop is finished?

```
async function processData(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  let db = mysql.createConnection({ ... });

  let statement = "INSERT INTO Kijiji SET ?";
  db.connect();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let row = data[i];
    scrape(row.url).then(adInfo => {
      //console.log(adInfo);
      let columns = {
        uuid: adInfo.adId
      };
      db.query(statement, columns, function(error) {
        if (error) throw error;
      });
    });
  }
  db.end();
}
```

> Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.

Comment: Where are your `await` calls?

Comment: Throwing inside callback is terrible idea

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop)

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Yes, you can.  It just won't be run in parallel.

Comment: Adding `await` before `scrape` makes the program much much slower.

Comment: @Alexander, I've been told not to use `ForEach` with asynchronous process...

Comment: It depends on the your needs, but I retract by previous statement.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't `await`ing anything.  Should be something like this:

```js
async function processData(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  let db = mysql.createConnection({ ... });

  let statement = "INSERT INTO Kijiji SET ?";
  await db.connect();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let row = data[i];
    const adInfo = await scrape(row.url);
    
    let columns = {
      uuid: adInfo.adId
    };
    
    await db.query(statement, columns)
  }
  db.end();
}
```

Or try it in parallel:

```js
async function processData(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  let db = mysql.createConnection({ ... });

  let statement = "INSERT INTO Kijiji SET ?";
  await db.connect();
  
  await Promise.all(data.map(async row => {
    const adInfo = await scrape(row.url);
    
    let columns = {
      uuid: adInfo.adId
    };
    
    await db.query(statement, columns)
  }));
  
  db.end();
}
```

Comment: Putting `await` infront of the `scape` makes the code extremely slow...

Comment: @Telenoobies Well, yes.  Your code isn't written to be run in parallel and it's slow now because it actually waits to do the operations before closing the DB.  Your alternative is to put it in a `Promise.all`.

Comment: @Telenoobies try with the parallel version.

Comment: Using `promise.all`? Looking into it right now... Thanks zero

Comment: VsCode warns that using `await query()` is unnecessary. And there is no error handling for `query()` either.