# Can not add new key and value to json object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

I am trying to add one new `key-value` pair to json object using JavaScript for loop but its not working as expected. I am explaining my code below.

```
for (var i=0; i < CustomerGroup.length; i++) {
            const customerCollection = loadMongoModel(CUSTOMERS_COLLECTION);
            const data = await customerCollection.find({_id: CustomerGroup[i]['CustomerId']});
            //console.log('data', data);
            CustomerGroup[i].CustomerName = data[0]['CustomerFullName'];
            console.log('data', data[0]['CustomerFullName']);
}
let result = {'record': CustomerGroup, 'count': CustomerGroupCount};
console.log('cust', result);
```

Here I need to add `CustomerName` key to `CustomerGroup` json object but it can not add this key and its value. I need after fetching some data the new value will be assigned to this json object with new key name.

Comment: what is the result of `console.log('data', data[0]['CustomerFullName']);`

Comment: @M14: one name is coming. Value is there.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the method. May be fetching method issue. https://jsfiddle.net/8xke46oj/

Comment: Yes, I am doing the same thing but its not working for me.

Comment: @user_agent What do you mean "one name is coming. Value is there"? What is happening?

Comment: @BrettEast: question was `what is the result of console.log('data', data[0]['CustomerFullName']);`  and I replied its printing one value.

Comment: @user_agent yes, but what are you expecting? What is the issue? You say it's not working as expecting, so what do you expect and what is it actually doing?

Comment: You can see my question. I need to add new key value pair to existing json.

Comment: I mean you haven't really explained what is going wrong. Anyway, the issue is that you're waiting for a value to return from an asynchronous call and a for loop won't wait before moving onto the next iteration, so my guess is only the last `CustomerGroup` customer name is being set, or they're all being set to the same thing - again, I'm trying to ask what result you get so that I can help answer. Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop