# Get result of Documents updated from mongoimport

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoimport

I'm upserting `Documents` into a `Collection` using `mongoimport`. I'm using `shelljs` to just run the actual `mongoimport` command the same way it'd be run through a CLI.

E.g.
`mongoimport docs.json -d DB -c Collection --jsonArray --upsertFields=foo,bar`
This just outputs the # of `Documents` updated - but doesn't give any further details on what exactly was changed.

However, I need to be able to see which documents were actually updated/inserted and then do something with these results. I would've thought there'd be some way to get the resulting `Object` IDs of these `documents` (perhaps through some `-v verbose` flag) - but upon doing research, it surprisingly seems that there is no way.

Does anybody know how to get the updated `Documents` using `mongoimport`? If it's truly not possible, is there some way to do this using `Mongoose`? Also, is there any way to check a diff of what exactly was updated on a `Document` i.e. what fields changed on an upsert? Thanks!

Comment: Are foo, bar nested paths like `fied.subField`? What are the types of foo, bar?

Comment: No, no nested fields fortunately. All types are 'String'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to get such information from a bulk operation.

Using Mongoose, you'll have to iterate through every document and compare the current document and the new document to get the fields that are different. You can either:

1. Make use of [`document.modifiedPaths()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-modifiedPaths) or [`document.directModifiedPaths()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-directModifiedPaths) by getting the diff before you update each document

```
const doc = await MyModel.findById(newDoc._id) // or .findOne for other upsert query conditions
if (doc) {
  const { foo, bar } = newDoc // assuming foo, are are top level fields
  doc.set({ foo, bar })
  const modifiedPaths = doc.directModifiedPaths() // should work if foo, bar are not objects
} else {
  // no previous doc, insert...
  await MyModel.create(newDoc)
}
```

2. Compare by yourself

```
const { foo, bar } = newDoc
const doc = await MyModel.findByIdAndUpdate(newDoc._id, { $set: { foo, bar } }, { new: false, upsert: true })
// or .findOneAndUpdate for other upsert query conditions
/* since we passed new: false, the operation will return the original document or null if not exists */

const { foo: newFoo, bar: newBar } = doc
// compare foo & newFoo, bar & newBar
```

Comment: How efficient would this be when trying to upsert ~5k records into a 1/4M Document Collection though? The actual `mongoimport` version of this is instant with an index. There's only half a dozen fields per document.

Comment: You can execute them in parallel, It wouldn't be an instant but it shouldn't take more 30 seconds. probably just 5-10 seconds.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to execute that in parallel. Only other parallel programming I've doing was in C using `threads` and in OpenCL

Comment: @user2402616 check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11488129) and [bluebird.js](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/why-promises.html)