# Run for loop in parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've the following code which use async to get data from **two functions** which is call to some back-end to get data, **the code works**.

```
    async function ac(token, gl) {
        for (const acc of gl) {
            let subsReqEu = sub(token, acc.guid, reg.1);
        
            let subsReqUs = sub(token, acc.guid, reg.2);
            // run both function async in parallel go get data from the backend
            const [se, su] = await Promise.all([axios(subsRE), axios(subsRU)])
        
          // here I got the response from the promise and should loop on it got get URL
            for (const sub of se.data.sub) {
                if (sub.url) {
                    return sub.url
                }
            }
           // the same for the second response of the promise all
            for (const sub of su.data.sub) {
                if (sub.url) {
                    return sub.url
                }
            }
    }
```

The `await` `Promise.all` return the data. Now I need to loop on each of the returned value
and find `url` and exit from the function, currently the loops are running in sequence,(assume I've Thousands of data one each loops)  how should **I run them im parallel** (the two `for` statement)  , as the first get result (url) will return the function with the value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop)

Comment: @Liam - no as my code after the promise is not asyc , its just sync code

Comment: You need to be careful of your usage or parallel and asynchronous, they're not the same thing

Comment: @Liam - yes I know. I run the async code , now I want to run the sync code (for loop) in parallel, how can I do it?

Comment: so how does the consumer of this method get the results? At some point someone is going to have to wait

Comment: @Liam the `ac` function called `var res = await ac(var1,var2)` , does it answer your question?

Comment: this is all very strange. Even if you could run those `for` async, which you can't as they don't do an IO why would you want to?

Comment: I think you want something like [`promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race). I started writing an answer but the more I read your code the less sense it makes.

Comment: @Liam - what doesnt make sense ? please explain! I run two async call to backend to get data, and then loop on it and when find url exit ? what is the issue with the code ?how would you do it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218834/discussion-between-beno-odr-and-liam).