# for loop with async in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await

Here is my code, I want to run the loop until `i<2*(actors.length-1)`

```
async function drawArrows(actors, timeout, drawArrow, i = 0) {
    drawArrow(i, timeout, actors.length-1);
    for(const actor of actors){
        new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            setTimeout (() => {
                resolve(drawArrows(actor,timeout,drawArrow, ++i));
            },timeout) ;
        });
    };
};
```

Where should this `i<2*(actors.length-1)` be fit for terminating this loop?

Comment: Why `async` when there's no `await`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop)

Comment: There is no need to async here imho, because there is nothing async happening. Just do a recursive function that executes itself inside the timeout.

Comment: @Andreas how this promise will be convert in await? Is it `cont act = await Promise.resolve(drawArrows(actor,timeout,drawArrow, ++i))` ....

Comment: @SajeebAhamed no. I have to use for loop inside this `drawArrows` function. And also how to remove this recursive call and do it with await method?

Comment: `Where should this` before the for loop

Comment: ```async function drawArrows(actors, timeout, drawArrow, i = 0) {
    const j = 2*(actors.length-1);
    drawArrow(i, timeout, actors.length-1);
    for(let i=0; i < j; ++i){
        await drawArrows(actors,timeout,drawArrow);
    };
};```     Changing the above. Loop is not executing with condition `i < j`

Comment: @JaromandaX `drawArrows may call an async function and await it to 
 * be ready` this is what I want to do using `for loop`.

Comment: when I said before the loop, I meant before the first line of the function - seeing as the first line of drawArrows calls drawArrows, you'll need to terminate somehow before that line otherwise what you got there is an infinite recursion -