# Closure timeout according to elapsed seconds

Tags: javascript, closures, iife

I'm studying closures but I don't understand why the second is always 1 instead of 2, 3, 4, 5 respectively. What I understand is here that since each function (even iife) has its own scope. Each `i` variable is captured its own stack actually that's why it allows changes of values of `i` though had been `var` used.

In the same way, `setTimeout` should catch each different `i` variables having 1,2,3,4,5 (seconds) respectively. But, it doesn't seem such as seen in the image. Could you help?

- Maybe it is helpful that `i` is not a free variable for
  `setTimeout`. (no idea it is of any relation)

Code

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  (function (i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(i)
    }, i * 1000)
  })(i)
}
```

[image: a]

Comment: what is your expected output of the `console.log`?

Comment: What's shown in the image is what you seem to expect (and is correct). What's the question? What are you expecting to be different? Also, side note: Since you're using `let`, each loop iteration gets its own execution context and its own copy of the `i` in the `for` statement, so you don't need the IIFE at all. You only needed it before `let`, because `var` behaves differently. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: *"I don't understand why the second is always 1"* The second what? I see only one code block in  your question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I expect that 1 second later 1, 2 secs later 2, 3 secs later 3, 4 secs later 4, 5 secs later 5. But 1,2,3,4,5 are printed 1 second elapsed each time as in the image.

Answer (score 1):

I think the use of `let` and an IIFE is throwing you off. Using an IIFE creates a new scope for the function parameters. A less known fact is that using [`let` in a loop](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-ForStatement) creates a new scope on every iteration.

e.g.

Using `var` and an IIFE.

```
// 'i' is declared here once
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

  // 'i' is declared again and takes a new scope every time the function is executed
  (function (i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(i) // references the nearest-scoped 'i'
    }, i * 1000)
  })(i)
}

// => 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Using `var` and no IIFE

```
// 'i' is declared here once
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(i) // references nearest-scoped 'i'
    }, i * 1000)
}

// => 6, 6, 6, 6, 6
```

Using `let` and no IIFE

```
// 'i' is given a new scope in every iteration
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(i)
    }, i * 1000)
}

// => 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Using `let` and an IIFE. This is exactly your example.

```
// 'i' is given a new scope in every iteration
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

  // 'i' is declared again and takes a new scope every time the function is executed
  (function (i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(i) // references the nearest-scoped 'i'
    }, i * 1000)
  })(i)
}

// => 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand too how the engine works, albeit `i` gives results as expected. I wouldn't expect persistently 1 second elapsing.

```js
    for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  (function (i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(i)
    }, (console.log(i),i * 1000))
  })(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you've said:

> I expect that 1 second later 1, 2 secs later 2, 3 secs later 3, 4 secs later 4, 5 secs later 5. But 1,2,3,4,5 are printed 1 second elapsed each time as in the image

That would be what would happen if you started the timer for 2 after the callback for timer 1 was called, but that's not what the code does. The code sets up the five timers all right away — a timer to show 1 after one second, a timer to show 2 after two seconds, a timer to show 3 after three seconds, etc. Since they all start at the same time, you see 1 after one second, 2 a second after that (two seconds after it was scheduled), 3 a second after that (three seconds after it was scheduled), etc.

To see that, let's show when we *start* each timer, and also how long it's been since the previous one fired. First, though, you don't need your IIFE, because you're using `let` in a `for` statement, so each loop iteration gets its own `i` variable. So here's your original code without the IIFE but adding the message when each timer starts and showing how long it was between when the timer started and when it fired; this will still just do them roughly one second apart instead of doing what you said you want:

```js
// Still doesn't do what you want, but shows that the IIFE isn't needed
// and when each timer is set up
let previousFired = Date.now();
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    console.log(`setting timer to show ${i} in ${i * 1000}ms`);
    const started = Date.now();
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(`${i} - fired after ${Date.now() - started}ms (${Date.now() - previousFired}ms after last)`);
        previousFired = Date.now();
    }, i * 1000);
}
```

If you want to wait one second to see 1, then wait a further two seconds to see 2, etc., either don't start the next timer until the previous one fires, or schedule them later. The latter is simpler, so let's do that:

```js
let total = 0;
let previousFired = Date.now();
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    total += i;
    console.log(`setting timer to show ${i} in ${total * 1000}ms`);
    const started = Date.now();
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(`${i} - fired after ${Date.now() - started}ms (${Date.now() - previousFired}ms after last)`);
        previousFired = Date.now();
    }, total * 1000);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can handle async loops awaiting a timedout Promise, then you can call a external function:

```js
function f(i) {
  console.log(i)
}

const runLoop = async () => {
    for(let i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, i * 1000))
        f(i * 1000);
    }
}

runLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the view but I'm in the search of _internals_...

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop#:~:text=This%20is%20because%20the%20for,when%20those%20async%20operations%20finish.