# Fadeout multiple elements with timeout only fades last one in list

Tags: javascript, dom, settimeout

I'm trying to fadeout message containers after a few seconds. Usually there's only one, and that works fine, but when there are 2 or more, only the last one seems to get processed.

**Code:**

```
function fadeOut(elementToFade) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementToFade);
    console.log(`fo element = ${element}, ${element.id}`)

    element.style.opacity = (parseFloat(element.style.opacity) - 0.1).toString();
    if (parseFloat(element.style.opacity) <= 0.0) {
        element.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        setTimeout("fadeOut(\"" + elementToFade + "\")", 150);
        // setTimeout("fadeOut(\"" + element.id + "\")", 150);
    }
};

var message_elements_nodelist = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^='message_container']");
var pauseBeforeFadeout = 5000;

for (var i = 0; i < message_elements_nodelist.length; i++) {
    var el = document.getElementById(message_elements_nodelist[i].id)
    console.log(`element = ${el}, ${el.id}`)
    setTimeout(function () {
        el.style.opacity = "1.0";
        fadeOut(el.id);
    }, pauseBeforeFadeout);
};
```

The console logging shows:

```
element = [object HTMLDivElement], message_container-0
element = [object HTMLDivElement], message_container-1
2fo element = [object HTMLDivElement], message_container-1
10fo element = [object HTMLDivElement], message_container-1
```

So the code finds both elements, but then the timeout only seems to get applied to the last one in the list and I cannot work out why this would be.

**Edit**

Putting in a `Promise` now looks like this:

```
const message_elements_nodelist = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^='message_container']")
const pauseBeforeFadeout = 5000

async function fadeOut(elementToFade) {
    const element = document.getElementById(elementToFade);
    console.log(`fo element = ${element}, ${element.id}`)

    element.style.opacity = (parseFloat(element.style.opacity) - 0.1).toString()
    if (parseFloat(element.style.opacity) <= 0.0) {
        element.style.display = "none"
    } else {
        setTimeout("fadeOut(\"" + elementToFade + "\")", 150)
    }
}

async function fadeOutAllMessages() {
    for (let i = 0; i < message_elements_nodelist.length; i++) {
        const el = document.getElementById(message_elements_nodelist[i].id)
        console.log(`element = ${el}, ${el.id}`)
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
            el.style.opacity = "1.0"
            fadeOut(el.id)    
        }, pauseBeforeFadeout))
    }
}

fadeOutAllMessages()
```

Unfortunately, now the first message is cleared, but the second isn't, and the `console.log` messages look like this:

```
element = [object HTMLDivElement], message_container-0
fo element = [object HTMLDivElement], message_container-0
9 fo element = [object HTMLDivElement], message_container-0
```

Those last 9 messsages appear 5 seconds after the first, so one `await` is working, then it seems to bundle them all through with only the 1st loop instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of asynchronous method (setTimeout in this case) is used inside for loop. Before the asynchronous method execution, variable `i` is already incremented (the loop does not wait for the asynchronous code inside), hence setTimeout will be executed multiple times and variable `i` is always at it's last value for all the callbacks.

Consider using `async/await` inside the loop.

```
async function yourFunction() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // wait for the promise before incrementing i and advancing the loop
        await new Promise(resolve => resolve(setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 
        1000)))
    }
}
```

The other solution is calling a function which is created outside of the loop.

```
const setDelay = (i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(i);
    }, 1000);
  }

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setDelay(i);
}
```

You can find more examples in this topic:
[Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop)

Comment: Thanks. This isn't entirely a solution though, sadly, though it's definitely an async issue as you say. I think the recursive call of `fadeOut` makes it more complicated than this. Adding this promise now only removes the first message ... seems like the 5 iterations that should be for message-1 ar enow done on message-0 ...

Comment: I just updated my answer to clarify the solution. It looks like You did not wrap `setTimeout` inside `resolve` method. `await new Promise(resolve => resolve(setTimeout(() => {...}, pauseBeforeFadeout)))` should solve the problem.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I need to spend some time (when I find some!) to properly understand how the promises stuff works! :)