# Unusual behavior of a JS for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a simple node.js script that iterates over a set of numbers. I can see on the for loop, it's being read properly.

However, when it goes to a db query function, it's only display the +1 value for all and not the actual index loop count.

**Result**

```
Processing:  1
Processing:  2
Processing:  3
Processing:  4
Processing:  5
Processing:  6
Processing:  7
Processing:  8
Processing:  9
Processing:  10
Create New Bottle for  11
Create New Bottle for  11
Create New Bottle for  11
Create New Bottle for  11
Create New Bottle for  11
Create New Bottle for  11
Create New Bottle for  11
Create New Bottle for  11
Create New Bottle for  11
Create New Bottle for  11
```

**Expected**

```
Processing:  1
Processing:  2
Processing:  3
Processing:  4
Processing:  5
Processing:  6
Processing:  7
Processing:  8
Processing:  9
Processing:  10
Create New Bottle for  1
Create New Bottle for  2
Create New Bottle for  3
Create New Bottle for  4
Create New Bottle for  5
Create New Bottle for  6
Create New Bottle for  7
Create New Bottle for  8
Create New Bottle for  9
Create New Bottle for  10
```

**Code**
ProcessBottleGeneration()

```
async function ProcessBottleGeneration() {

    try {


        var start = 1
        var end = 10
        
        for (count = start; count <= end; count++) {
            console.log("Processing: ", count)

            GetByUniqueCode(count).then(result => {

                if (result == undefined) {
                    console.log("Create New Bottle for ", count)

                    // AddBottleData(bottle).then(res => {
                    //     console.log(res)
                    // }).catch(err => {
                    //     console.log(err)  
                    // })
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Bottle exist already for ", count)
                }

                // process.exit()
            })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log("error: ", error)
                    return error
                })

        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("ProcessBottleGeneration.Error:")
        console.log(error)
        return error
    }
}

function GetByUniqueCode(unique_code) {
    var where = [
        unique_code
    ]

    let sql = `SELECT  *
        FROM
            plants_bottles
        WHERE
            unique_code =  ?;`

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query(sql, [where], function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err)
            } else {
                return resolve(result[0])
            }
        });
    })
}

function AddBottleData(d) {
    console.log("AddBottleData:", d)

    let sql = `INSERT INTO plants_bottles SET ?;`

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        query = db.query(sql, [d], function (err, result) {

            console.log("AddBottleData.result:", result)
            if (err) {
                return reject(err)
            } else {
                return resolve(result)
            }

        });
    })

}
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: You need an `array` of `Promises`, and `Promise.all()` to resolve it.

Comment: `GetByUniqueCode` is `async` and not `awaited` so the iteration value is incremented to 11 before any of those promises return and log the value.

Comment: Getting confused now

Comment: Multiple ways to Rome I say.

Comment: @jxreact Please read this related post [asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop)

Comment: GetByUniqueCode  is async operation and therefore this is expected behavior. If you want exact index use let instead of var . Like 

 for (let count = 0; count <= end; count++) {
}