# Strange behavior inside async function

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm learning Promises and I tried to fetch some data inside an async function.

Here's the snippet -

```js
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";

let jsonPlaceholder = axios.create({
  baseURL : "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"
})

let fetchData = async () => {
  console.log("INSIDE FETCH DATA FUNCTION")
  let response = await jsonPlaceholder.get('/users');
  return response.data;
}

let runSetTimeoutTenTimes = () => {
  for(let i=0; i<10; i++) {
    setTimeout(async () => {
       let data = await fetchData();          
       console.log("HERE IS THE USER DATA....",data);
    })
  }
}

runSetTimeoutTenTimes();
```

I was expecting the output similar to the below format in console:

```
INSIDE FETCH DATA FUNCTION
HERE'S THE DATA....
(10) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

INSIDE FETCH DATA FUNCTION
HERE'S THE DATA....
(10) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
.
.
.
```

However I am getting data in the below format:

[image: Screenshot]

It looks like `fetchData` is run 10 times and then fetched data are logged one by one.

[Here is the Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-cohen-cfey5?file=/src/index.js:0-529)

What am I missing here ?

**EDIT:**

If I replace the `fetchData` and `runSetTimeoutTenTimes` with the below functions I am getting the desired result:

```
let fetchData_1 = async () => {
  console.log("INSIDE FETCH DATA FUNCTION")
  return;
}

let runSetTimeoutTenTimes = () => {
  for(let i=0; i<10; i++) {
    setTimeout(async () => {
       await fetchData();          
       console.log("HERE IS THE USER DATA....");
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop)

Comment: What's the point of the setTimeout?

Comment: @Seblor No, please see the edit.

Comment: @Seblor That question isn't a good dupe target for this. The base scenario is similar, but the underlying problems are very different.

Answer (score 1):

Realise that what occurs *before* the `await` inside `fetchData` will execute immediately, while the part that *follows* it will run later, asynchronously.

As your timers expired quite quickly, the 10 calls to `fetchData` are made quite quickly one after the other, ... before any of the awaited `get` promises are resolved, and so the synchronous part of `fetchData` is executed 10 times before any of the `return` statements in `fetchData` are executed, since those can only execute when the `get` promises resolve.

So that explains why you first get a bunch of "INSIDE FETCH DATA FUNCTION" messages and only then get a series of "HERE IS THE USER DATA....".

If you want to serialise this completely, then the easiest is to *promisify* `setTimeout` as follows:

```
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";

let jsonPlaceholder = axios.create({
  baseURL : "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"
})

let fetchData = async () => {
  console.log("INSIDE FETCH DATA FUNCTION")
  let response = await jsonPlaceholder.get('/users');
  return response.data;
}

// promisified setTimeout:
let delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

let runSetTimeoutTenTimes = async () => { // <-- make async
  for(let i=0; i<10; i++) {
    // Here comes the timeout, only when it expires can we proceed below:
    await delay(100);
    let data = await fetchData();          
    console.log("HERE IS THE USER DATA....",data);
  }
}

runSetTimeoutTenTimes();
```

Of course, this time out is not necessary, so you can leave out `await delay(100)` completely. Then you have a situation where the next get request is made once the previous one is resolved.