# How to use arcGIS Leaflet query run and push to Array during query and return a complete Array

Tags: arrays, esri, arcgis-js-api, esri-leaflet

I am querying each point of a polygon object (e in this case) using esri leaflet. To do so I have the following function that I use on a polgon that is passed to it:

```
 const queryFeature = (e: any) => {
    let nearbyCollection: any = new Array()
    console.log(e)
    const latlngParcel = new L.Polygon(e)
    console.log(latlngParcel)
    for (let n=0; n < e[0].length; n++) {
      let point = L.latLng(e[0][n])
      featureRef
      .query()
      .nearby(point, 1)
      .run(function (error: any, featureCollection: any) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
      } else {
        featureCollection.features.forEach((i: any) => {
        nearbyCollection.push({ id: i.id, name: i.properties.Situs1})})
      }
    })
    };
    return nearbyCollection
  };
```

Which when I run console.log on the array "nearbyCollection" it shows it's contents however if I run nearbyCollection.length it is 0.

[image]

Furthermore I cant iterate over the array or pass this information to a new Array...

I am guessing it is because I am pushing to this array during an async call but I am not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: I would suggest beautifying the code: https://beautifier.io

Answer (score 2):

the problem is indeed the async call you're making within your loop.

i'd recommend checking out 'Serializing with promises and async/await' section of the answer below...

[Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop)

it sounds a little strange that you're making a web request to do a spatial query for each individual vertex of your parcel polygons, but i'm sure you have your reasons.

Comment: Thanks, even though it isn't returning a Promise you are suggesting I create a Promise from the results, when they are fulfilled push to an Array. I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [John's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73805438/3541972). I think what he is suggesting you is to do something like this:

```js
async const queryFeature = (e: any) => {
    let nearbyCollection: any = new Array()
    console.log(e)
    const latlngParcel = new L.Polygon(e)
    console.log(latlngParcel)
    for (let n = 0; n < e[0].length; n++) {
        let point = L.latLng(e[0][n])
        await featureRef
            .query()
            .nearby(point, 1)
            .run(function(error: any, featureCollection: any) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    return;
                } else {
                    featureCollection.features.forEach((i: any) => {
                        nearbyCollection.push({
                            id: i.id,
                            name: i.properties.Situs1
                        })
                    })
                }
            })
    }
    return nearbyCollection;
};

const nearbyCollection = queryFeature.then(nearbyCollection => nearbyCollection).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

**Note:** Update, I'm checking do not 100% sure if this will work, in case it doesn't, I would wrap the `featureRef.query().nearby(point, 1)...` in [a function like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#awaiting_a_promise_to_be_fulfilled).