# For loop randomly goes from 1 to 0

Tags: javascript, node.js

Basically, what happens is every time I refresh my page, there's a slight chance that my for loop goes from 1 to 0. I don't know why this happens, but it's affecting the way my images layer over each other.

I tried to use a foreach loop, but it still gave me the same results.

Here's the code to the for loop:

```js
for (let index = 0; index < Img.length; index++) {
  const element = Img[index];
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/assets/textures' + element, function(err, data) {
    console.log("Index: " + index);
  });
};
```

And the array is pretty straight forward.

```js
let Img = ["/red.png", "/face.png"];
```

I'm doing this all on server. NodeJS

Comment: It’s more likely you’ve misunderstand the async nature of `readFile`.

Comment: What's your question? Do you want to know, why this happens? Do you want to achieve a specific behavior?

Comment: I don’t want it to randomly go from 1 to 0. I am layering images and it messes up the layers.

Comment: My solution is: Use the promise version of `fs.readFile`. Replace the loop with `Img.map` and map each image to a promise. Await all promises with `Pormise.all`. I guess, your actual callback isn't a simple `console.log`. There should be hundreds of duplicates, but it's difficult to search for them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop#11488129) I guess you want _"**Run asynchronous operations in parallel and use Promise.all() to collect results in order**"_

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
let Img = ["/red.png", "/face.png"];

async function prepareImages() {
  for (let index = 0; index < Img.length; index++) {
    const element = Img[index];
    await loadImage(element)
  };
}

function loadImage(element) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(`${__dirname}/assets/textures${element}`, function(err, data) {
      console.log("dir ", `${__dirname}/assets/textures${element}`);
      if(err) {
        reject("Error: ", err)
      }
      
      resolve(data);
    });
  })
}
```